# need to upload an xml file, parse and store in database without storing file at any physical physical location

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to upload an XML file, parse and store the data in the database without storing file at any physical location( if possible we can store it in request). I am using spring, spring REST.

Comment: Could you please provide the XML file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the XML data using Jackson, GSON,etc library by creating a REST API(as you want to use RESTfull web service). It would be quite easy to parse if you know the contract of your XML file by creating POJOs.